# Change color of the first selected option in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of the first selection and let the rest of the selection-options remain in its inherit color which is black.

However, I'm unable to get it going. Currently; all colors are in #ccc. I want the first option which is disabled to be #ccc and the rest in inherit color.

Here's the HTML:

```
<select class="form-control select form__blank">
  <option disabled selected value> - select - </option>
  <option>Full Furnished</option>
  <option>Semi Furnished</option>
  <option>UnFurnished</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.form-control {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #323a56;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.select {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #323a56;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-position: right 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  height: inherit;
}
.form__blank:first-child {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/v9gasouf/**

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: does .form__blank option:first-child in your css works ?

Comment: You can use `select option:disabled` css selector.

Comment: Tried already. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The *main* problem on this is styling `options`/`select` its a very difficult task because each browser acts different or uses a different way to display them.

You have there a [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript) with a very good explanation why and a lots of possibles workarounds.

For Chrome v.57.0.2987 you can use the CSS selector: `select option:disabled` and would do the work:

```css
.form-control {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #323a56;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.select {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid #323a56;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-position: right 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  height: inherit;
}
.form__blank select option:disabled {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control select form__blank">
  <option disabled selected value> - select - </option>
  <option>Full Furnished</option>
  <option>Semi Furnished</option>
  <option>UnFurnished</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I want the ` - select - ` to be in color #ccc as is shown in the JSFiddle. That should not be changed. However, when I select other fields, the color should be changed to `inherit` or #000.

Comment: @ElaineByene Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm on Mac Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @ElaineByene The problem is pure CSS for `option` styles cross browsers are hard to archive, it means maybe you archive the correct behavior on Chrome but will look totally diferent at Firefox, you have a very good explanation with solutions there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do

```
.form__blank:first-child {
   color: #ccc;
}
```

but instead :

```
.form__blank option:first-child {
   color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Tried this actually but didn't work. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Select first child of option instead of select.

```
option:first-child {
 color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Tried this already but didn't work. I tried with `form__blank option:first-child` too.

Comment: what if i will give you JavaScript solution?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of styling `:first-child` You can style using `[disabled]` property

```
select option:disabled{
  color:red;
}
```

You can also check the below fiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/achuakshuu/e97nqLuh/

Comment: No. I don't see any red color! Which browser are you using? I'm on Mac Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit). I event tried it on Safari. Doesn't see any red color.

Comment: I am using windows10 chrome. You want the -select- option only to be in red color or selected value has to change the color

Comment: Only the -select- to be in red. The rest remains as it is.

Comment: change [disabled] to :disabled

Comment: Nothing! https://jsfiddle.net/e97nqLuh/2/ I'm suppose to see -select- but default but that's not the case either :/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<select id="selid" class="form-control select form__blank">
.....
</select>
```

JS(JQuery)

```
$('#selid').change(function () {
$(this).find('option').css('color', 'inherit');
$(this).find('option:selected').css('color', 'red');
}).trigger('change');
```

or

```
$('#selid').change(function () {
$(this).css("color", $("option").css("color", 'inherit'));
$(this).css("color", $("option:selected").css("color", 'blue'));
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: As per your question, selected item highlighted

Comment: I don't know. Now, all the colors changed to #ccc :( I guess it's my Chrome version!!

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/v9gasouf/6/. In last fiddle i have applied for background

Comment: I give up!! It's not working. The other options apart from -select- changed to #ccc. That's the same stage as where I was when I asked the question :(